# Расчет стоимости доставки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Задача стоит наверное многим знакомая, сделать расчет стоимости доставки от Мкад(ближайшей точки шоссе до поставленной), я соорудил вот такое "[Решение](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PyQKMJ)" , но очевидно пока ковырялся наткнулся на [решение песочницы с доставкой](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator), и мне не захотелось страдать с обнулением маршрута если есть > 1 и т.д + решение с песочницы очень прикольное и очень мне подходит, но при попытке внедрить мое решение в решение с песочнице я  сразу столкнулся с проблемой, что я должен знать точку А, до того как определил точку B а я с моим решением не могу такого провернуть, так как точку А я получаю с помощью getClosestTo , я еще рассматривал способ с помощью постановки точки А в центр Мкада и сегментацией маршрута, на попала в полигон и не попала, но мне текущий приглянулся больше, может быть я не прав, подскажите как мне лучше объединить решения, или может есть все таки лучшая альтернатива для моей задачи

```
ymaps.ready(init);
```

function init() {

```
var coords = [
    [55.882453,37.726268],[55.829798,37.828943],[55.81387,37.839307],
    [55.776965,37.843213],[55.76914,37.843599],[55.76715,37.843459],
    [55.755311,37.842912],[55.743971,37.842462],[55.74139,37.842462],
    [55.729773,37.840841],[55.718659,37.83949],[55.711842,37.837612],
    [55.707838,37.835531],[55.686682,37.831336],[55.656874,37.839876],
    [55.640379,37.820188],[55.617568,37.78268],[55.591371,37.729669],
    [55.575349,37.688267],[55.572562,37.650265],[55.573428,37.635481],
    [55.574477,37.61927],[55.575735,37.596535],[55.580792,37.572288],
    [55.580433,37.573951],[55.611022,37.491532],[55.615649,37.486135],
    [55.625624,37.474495],[55.631391,37.467703],[55.638783,37.459056],
    [55.656307,37.437952],[55.662309,37.431869],[55.668779,37.426118],
    [55.682621,37.416301],[55.701565,37.398492],[55.713535,37.385381],
    [55.723509,37.380371],[55.764978,37.368783],[55.770155,37.369041],
    [55.789806,37.372517],[55.808849,37.387924],[55.815522,37.389866],
    [55.821097,37.391293],[55.825213,37.392773],[55.830515,37.394436],
    [55.832786,37.395166],[55.83278,37.39331],[55.834024,37.395369],
    [55.849635,37.392194],[55.851759,37.393234],[55.858633,37.397022],
    [55.865276,37.402386],[55.873396,37.417331],[55.876755,37.42791],
    [55.881888,37.444851],[55.887472,37.482777],[55.908124,37.543781],
    [55.911056,37.570046],[55.911149,37.581182],[55.910028,37.588767],
    [55.895786,37.663247],[55.895496,37.673203],[55.891982,37.707107]
];  

var myPlacemark;

var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.73, 37.75],
    zoom: 8,
    behaviors:['default', 'scrollZoom']
});

myMap.events.add('click', function (e){
    var coord = e.get('coords');
    if (myPlacemark) {
        myPlacemark.geometry.setCoordinates(coord);
    }else{
        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(coord, {
            iconCaption: 'поиск...'
        }, {
            preset: 'islands#violetDotIconWithCaption',
            draggable: true
        });
        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
        myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
            getAddress(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
        });
    }
    getAddress(coord);
    //point click
    console.log(coord);

    var arPlaseMarks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
        arPlaseMarks[i] = new ymaps.Placemark(coords[i]);
    }
    var rezz = ymaps.geoQuery(arPlaseMarks).addToMap(myMap).setOptions('visible', false);
    var closestObject = rezz.getClosestTo(coord);

    ymaps.route([
        closestObject.geometry.getCoordinates(),
        coord
    ]).then(function(route){
        myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
        var distance = Math.round(route.getLength()/1000);
        myPlacemark.properties.set({iconContent: distance});

    });

});

function getAddress(coord){
    myPlacemark.properties.set('iconCaption', 'поиск...');
    ymaps.geocode(coord).then(function (res) {
        var firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
        myPlacemark.properties
            .set({
                iconCaption: [
                    firstGeoObject.getLocalities().length ? firstGeoObject.getLocalities() : firstGeoObject.getAdministrativeAreas(),
                    firstGeoObject.getThoroughfare() || firstGeoObject.getPremise()
                ].filter(Boolean).join(', '),
                balloonContent: firstGeoObject.getAddressLine()
            });
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Можно попробовать нарисовать полигон который покрывает Москву вместе с МКАД, воспользовавшись этим примером https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon определить часть маршрута, которая выходит за пределы МКАД и вывести это значение.

Comment: как я писал выше, я не очень хочу пользоваться этим способом, т.к с точки зрения UX пользователь при первой визуализации маршрута может подумать, что участок внутри мкада тоже учитывается, а с моим решением он сразу видит, что маршрут строиться от кольца мкада, но походу из-за того что А неопределена изначально до создание собственной точки B придется делать да через сегментацию, с другой стороны я могу попадающий в полигон участок маршрута делать прозрачным

Answer (score 0):

У меня был похожий вопрос [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185875/Не-выполняется-построение-маршрута/1186871#1186871](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1185875/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0/1186871#1186871)

я его решил таким образом:

```js
function OpredelenieTochkiPeresecheniyaSMKAD(coords){
    
        var coordsCenter = [55.77183533, 37.64730933];  
        ymaps.route([coordsCenter,coords]).then(
            function (res) {
            // Объединим в выборку все сегменты маршрута.
                var pathsObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(res.getPaths()),
                    edges = [];
                
                // Переберем все сегменты и разобьем их на отрезки.
                pathsObjects.each(function (path) {
                    var coordinates = path.geometry.getCoordinates();
                    for (var i = 1, l = coordinates.length; i < l; i++) {
                        edges.push({
                            type: 'LineString',
                            coordinates: [coordinates[i], coordinates[i - 1]]
                        });
                    }
                });

                var routeObjects = ymaps.geoQuery(edges)
                    .add(res.getWayPoints())
                    .add(res.getViaPoints())
                    .setOptions('strokeWidth', 3)
                    .addToMap(myMap),
                // Найдем все объекты, попадающие внутрь МКАД.
                objectsInMoscow = routeObjects.searchInside(myPolygonMKAD),
                // Найдем объекты, пересекающие МКАД.
                boundaryObjects = routeObjects.searchIntersect(myPolygonMKAD);
                // Объекты за пределами МКАД получим исключением полученных выборок из
                // исходной.
                PeresechenieMKAD = routeObjects.remove(objectsInMoscow).remove(boundaryObjects).get(0).geometry.getBounds()[0];
                routeObjects.remove(objectsInMoscow).remove(boundaryObjects).addToMap(myMap);
                routeObjects.removeFromMap(myMap);
                vivodStoimosti(PeresechenieMKAD,coords);
            },
            function(error){
                      alert('Error'+error.msg);
            },
        );
    }
    function vivodStoimosti(PeresechenieMKAD, coords){  
        
        var summaZakaza = 3010;
        
        if(myPolygonMKAD.geometry.contains(coords) || myPolygonKhimki.geometry.contains(coords)) {

            // Адрес внутри МКАД

        } else {

            // Адрес за МКАД
            // Расчет расстояния до адреса

            multiRouteModelCenter = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRouteModel([PeresechenieMKAD,coords],{
                results: 1,
                avoidTrafficJams: false
            });
                        
            multiRouteViewCenter = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(multiRouteModelCenter);
            
            
            myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRouteViewCenter);
            
            // Добавляем мультимаршрут на карту.        
            multiRouteViewCenter.model.events.add("requestsuccess", function (event) {
                var routes = event.get("target").getRoutes();
                for (var i = 0, l = routes.length; i < l; i++) {
                    distance = routes[i].properties.get("distance").text;
                    // тут сам расчет доставки ...
        
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().properties.set('DeliveryCost_0', DeliveryCost_0)
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().properties.set('DeliveryCost_9', DeliveryCost_9)
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().properties.set('DeliveryCost_30', DeliveryCost_30)
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().properties.set('summaZakaza', summaZakaza)
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().options.set('balloonContentBodyLayout', myBalloonContentBodyLayout);
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().options.set('iconContentLayout', myIconContentLayout);
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().options.set('balloonContentLayout', myBalloonContentLayout);
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().options.set('preset', 'twirl#nightStretchyIcon');
                    multiRouteViewCenter.getActiveRoute().balloon.open()
                    break;
                }
            });
        };
    };
```

Comment: А есть полный код?